# What does "to twist one's words" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I don't understand what twisting words means. I've heard people say "s/he is twisting my words", but what would that mean?

Comment: [twist someone's words](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/twist+words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To twist one's words means that the person doing it is trying to misrepresent what you have said. They are taking your words out of context and twisting (changing) them to make them sound negative or the opposite of what you are actually saying.

Example:

> — So, you're saying that because Hitler was democratically elected into office, the extermination of Jews was okay?
>   — Stop **twisting my words**! That's hot what I meant. I said that despite all the evil he did, he was nonetheless the democratically elected leader of the 1930s Germany.